# How do I split conversations in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I posted an ad on a website and when people respond, I get an email from post@example.com titled like this:

> Reply to your "1999 Pontiac Sunfire - As Is" ad on Example.com

If two people reply to my advert in one day, I get two of these from the same bot sender and they end up in the same Gmail conversation, even though they're really from two different people.

Is it possible for me to "split" this conversation into two or more conversations so that I can keep track of which people I've replied to and who I have not?

Comment: The accepted answer is inaccurate, there is a way.  See hpmc's answer below.

Comment: Especially crappy if Gmail for some reason groups together unrelated messages from distinct people. :-/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to split Gmail threads. However, you can mark some messages as "unread from here". When you reply, change the title and reply in a new composing window, so that at least the follow-ups are split.

Comment: See my answer below, it is actually possible now.

Answer (score 15):

You can also turn off conversation view, which is a new Gmail feature as of today:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/turn-off-gmails-conversation-view.html

Comment: This helps somewhat, as you can at least label the messages individually, but once you turn conversation view back on(my problem isn't with the view but the fact these messages have nothing to do with each other), they still get collapsed together and come up in each other's label results.

Answer (score 13):

You could always forward the conversation to yourself with a new subject. You'll lose the original sender, but you can add that to the message body so it's still searchable.

Also don't forget to include attachments when replying (if you want to keep them)
[image]

Comment: better yet, edit the subject line to add the sender's name

Comment: Shame it's not possible to do this automatically in a filter.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 12):

When replying you can change the subject, that will push the conversation from that point forward to a new conversation.

Answer (score 10):

We (Streak) just added the ability to split up threads into smaller ones by selecting messages you want to move to a new thread. If you're still looking for this feature it may be helpful: https://www.streak.com/split-gmail-conversation-threads-break

Comment: Is the split done by Streak also visible in a regular GMail app on iOS/Android?

Comment: @yurkennis I have checked that the split is also visible in the Gmail app on iOS, it works by altering the Subject field.

Comment: Streak changes the date of the newest email among the emails you select to split off. To circumvent this, reply to yourself, and select that reply to be split off together with the other emails you want to split off. Then you can delete that reply. (A future version of Streak might automatize this workaround.)

Comment: Update: Apparently instead of fixing this problem, it got worse: my aforementioned workaround currently doesn't seem to work. @aloo Please at least reverse it to the way it used to work, thanks! And in any case thanks for creating Streak!

Comment: "Sorry, Streak currently only supports Google Chrome, Safari, and Microsoft Edge."

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can split conversations using a regular IMAP-client. Move one of the two messages to a different folder (label) using the IMAP-client and then move it back to the original folder (label).

If you set the draft flag in your external IMAP-client you can also edit the message to add keywords etc.

Comment: Just tried it with Mail.app under OS X Mavericks 10.9.3, and it doesn't work. Could you give step-by-step instructions to follow that give the result as of now?

Comment: I used Mulberry to do this. It is a free download. Have never tried with Mail.app. Mulberry has some learning curve so maybe you should try with Thunderbird first.

Answer (score -3):

Click on the cog icon and scroll down to and click on settings. Scroll down to "conversation view" and click to turn it off. Save at the bottom, log out then log back in and all of your emails will be separated regardless of subject :)

Comment: Perhaps you can show us, with a screenshot, where the cog exactly is?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/7147) already suggested turning off conversation view.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to split a thread - implementation merely turns off conversation view Gmail-wide, which will affect all threads, not just the one the OP wants to split.

Answer (score -5):

Log into your Gmail.

[image: Settings Tab]

Simply click on the Settings Tab (Cog shaped wheel) as per the image above, then click on Settings. Scroll down to "Conversation View", select conversation view "On" button.

Scroll to bottom of screen and click on "Save Changes" tab.

You're done!

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants to "split" a SPECIFIC conversation, not disable conversation view completely.

Comment: Also, even if that was what they wanted, this is about turning it *on*, not *off*...