# Is there a way to separate out Only Some individual emails from conversations in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split conversations in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/how-do-i-split-conversations-in-gmail)

There are some emails that I want to separate out from conversations in Conversation View in Gmail.

Is it possible to separate out Only Some conversations?

This is for system-generated emails from jobs posted on http://Wordfruit.com -- jobs land in my Gmail inbox on top of one another -- in the same conversation.

I want to separate out these emails so I can apply labels to individual emails.

But I want to keep Conversation View for my conversations with people.

So I only want to separate out some emails.

Comment: Also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12064/can-i-archive-only-certain-messages-within-a-conversation